# Why can't Swift add two Ints?

Tags: swift

When I try the following:

```
var somestring = "5"
var somenumber = 2
var newnumber:Int = Int(somestring) + somenumber
```

I get this error:

> binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two Int operands

What am I doing wrong?  Shouldn't '+' be valid for adding two Ints?

Comment: you could actually tell how with an Update....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a really weird error message. The actual problem is that you can't simply construct Ints from Strings. The proper way to do that is with the `toInt` method like so:

```
var newnumber:Int = something.toInt()! + somenumber
```

Notice that `toInt` returns an optional that's unwrapped with `!`. If you're not sure the string represents an integer, error handling needs to be added as well.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72) "??" to return 0 instead of nil when trying to extract the value from your string:

```
let someString = "5"
let someNumber = 2
let newNumber = (someString.toInt() ?? 0) + someNumber

println(newNumber) // 7

let anotherString = "a"
let anotherNumber = (anotherString.toInt() ?? 0) + someNumber

println(anotherNumber) // 2
```

update: **Xcode 7.1.1 • Swift 2.1**

```
let someString = "5"
let someNumber = 2
let newNumber = (Int(someString) ?? 0) + someNumber

print(newNumber) // 7

let anotherString = "a"
let anotherNumber = (Int(anotherString) ?? 0) + someNumber   // 2
```